# Largest product in a grid

Tags: python, beginner, project-euler

[Project Euler problem 11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11) says:

> In the 20×20 grid below, four numbers along a diagonal line have been marked in bold. [*red in the original*]
>
> `08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08`
>   `49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00`
>   `81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65`
>   `52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91`
>   `22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80`
>   `24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50`
>   `32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10`**`26`**`38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70`
>   `67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95`**`63`**`94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21`
>   `24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17`**`78`**`78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72`
>   `21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35`**`14`**`00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95`
>   `78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92`
>   `16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57`
>   `86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58`
>   `19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40`
>   `04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66`
>   `88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69`
>   `04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36`
>   `20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16`
>   `20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54`
>   `01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48`
>
> The product of these numbers is 26 × 63 × 78 × 14 = 1788696.
>
> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

So, I coded this:

```
grid=[8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8,
49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0,
81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65,
52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91,
22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80,
24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50,
32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70,
67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21,
24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72,
21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95,
78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92,
16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57,
86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58,
19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40,
4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66,
88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69,
4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36,
20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16,
20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54,
1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48]

largest=[0,0,0,0]

#horizontal and verticle

for h in xrange(0,20):
    for hsub in xrange(0,17):
        if grid[h*10+hsub]*grid[h*10+hsub+1]*grid[h*10+hsub+2]*grid[h*10+hsub+3] > largest[0]:
            largest[0] = grid[h*10+hsub]*grid[h*10+hsub+1]*grid[h*10+hsub+2]*grid[h*10+hsub+3]


        if grid[(hsub*20)+h]* grid[((hsub+1)*20)+h]* grid[((hsub+2)*20)+h]* grid[((hsub+3)*20)+h] > largest[1]:
            largest[1] = grid[(hsub*20)+h]* grid[((hsub+1)*20)+h]* grid[((hsub+2)*20)+h]* grid[((hsub+3)*20)+h]

#diagonal right and left

for r in xrange(0,17):
    for rsub in xrange (0,17):
        if grid[(rsub*20)+r]* grid[((rsub+1)*20)+1+r]* grid[((rsub+2)*20)+2+r]* grid[((rsub+3)*20)+3+r] > largest[2]:
            largest[2] = grid[(rsub*20)+r]* grid[((rsub+1)*20)+1+r]* grid[((rsub+2)*20)+2+r]* grid[((rsub+3)*20)+3+r] 

        if grid[(rsub*20)+3+r]* grid[((rsub+1)*20)+2+r]* grid[((rsub+2)*20)+1+r]* grid[((rsub+3)*20)+r] > largest[3]:
            largest[3] =  grid[(rsub*20)+3+r]* grid[((rsub+1)*20)+2+r]* grid[((rsub+2)*20)+1+r]* grid[((rsub+3)*20)+r]

print max(largest)
```

Even though I got the answer right, I am quite unsatisfied with my current code. I feel as though it's very very messy. I have always thought that in order to become a good programmer, one has to code in a neat and elegant manner.

I am a complete beginner. What should I do differently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code would be much simpler if you'd use a list of lists for the matrix:

```
grid = [
  [...],
  [...],
  ...
]
```

each row is a list itself, so to get the element at `(x, y)` we can now say `grid[y][x]`. This is massively more readable than your previous `grid[y*20+x]`.

Your code now looks like:

```
#horizontal and vertical
for h in xrange(0,20):
    for hsub in xrange(0,17):
        if grid[h][hsub]*grid[h][hsub+1]*grid[h][hsub+2]*grid[h][hsub+3] > largest[0]:
            largest[0] = grid[h][hsub]*grid[h][hsub+1]*grid[h][hsub+2]*grid[h][hsub+3]
        if grid[hsub][h]* grid[hsub+1][h]* grid[hsub+2][h]* grid[hsub+3][h] > largest[1]:
            largest[1] = grid[hsub][h]* grid[hsub+1][h]* grid[hsub+2][h]* grid[hsub+3][h]

#diagonal right and left
for r in xrange(0,17):
    for rsub in xrange (0,17):
        if grid[rsub][r]* grid[rsub+1][1+r]* grid[rsub+2][2+r]* grid[rsub+3][3+r] > largest[2]:
            largest[2] = grid[rsub][r]* grid[rsub+1][1+r]* grid[rsub+2][2+r]* grid[rsub+3][3+r] 
        if grid[rsub][3+r]* grid[rsub+1][2+r]* grid[rsub+2][1+r]* grid[rsub+3][r] > largest[3]:
            largest[3] =  grid[rsub][3+r]* grid[rsub+1][2+r]* grid[rsub+2][1+r]* grid[rsub+3][r]
```

At this step I also removed uneccessary empty lines from your code.

We see that each expression for summing adjacent cells in a certain direction is repeated two times. We can avoid this by using a variable each time:

```
#horizontal and vertical
for h in xrange(0,20):
    for hsub in xrange(0,17):
        horizontal = grid[h][hsub] * grid[h][hsub+1] * grid[h][hsub+2] * grid[h][hsub+3]
        vertical   = grid[hsub][h] * grid[hsub+1][h] * grid[hsub+2][h] * grid[hsub+3][h]
        if horizontal > largest[0]:
            largest[0] = horizontal
        if vertical > largest[1]:
            largest[1] = vertical

#diagonal right and left
for r in xrange(0,17):
    for rsub in xrange (0,17):
        right_diagonal = grid[rsub][0+r] * grid[rsub+1][1+r] * grid[rsub+2][2+r] * grid[rsub+3][3+r]
        left_diagonal  = grid[rsub][3+r] * grid[rsub+1][2+r] * grid[rsub+2][1+r] * grid[rsub+3][r]
        if right_diagonal > largest[2]:
            largest[2] = right_diagonal
        if left_diagonal > largest[3]:
            largest[3] = left_diagonal
```

This format makes it much easier to spot errors – just as I'm writing this, I see that we forgot a `+1` in the left diagonal (corrected in the previous code as well).

All of these products look similar: We have some starting point and a direction. We then take three steps in that direction, and multiply all numbers. We could abstract this:

```
def product_in_direction(grid, start, direction, steps):
    x0, y0 = start
    dx, dy = direction
    product = 1
    for n in range(steps):
        product *= grid[y0 + n*dy][x0 + n*dx]
    return product
```

Now the rest of the code simplifies to:

```
#horizontal and vertical
for h in xrange(0,20):
    for hsub in xrange(0,17):
        horizontal = product_in_direction(grid, (hsub, h), (1, 0), 4)
        vertical   = product_in_direction(grid, (h, hsub), (0, 1), 4)
        if horizontal > largest[0]:
            largest[0] = horizontal
        if vertical > largest[1]:
            largest[1] = vertical

#diagonal right and left
for r in xrange(0,17):
    for rsub in xrange (0,17):
        right_diagonal = product_in_direction(grid, (rsub, r  ), (1,  1), 4)
        left_diagonal  = product_in_direction(grid, (rsub, r+3), (1, -1), 4)
        if right_diagonal > largest[2]:
            largest[2] = right_diagonal
        if left_diagonal > largest[3]:
            largest[3] = left_diagonal
```

As a next step, we will remove the unnecesary `largest` array: Why do we need to remember four different values when we only want the largest?

```
largest = 0

#horizontal and vertical
for h in xrange(0,20):
    for hsub in xrange(0,17):
        largest = max(
            product_in_direction(grid, (hsub, h), (1, 0), 4), # horizontal
            product_in_direction(grid, (h, hsub), (0, 1), 4), # vertical
            largest,
        )

#diagonal right and left
for r in xrange(0,17):
    for rsub in xrange (0,17):
        largest = max(
            product_in_direction(grid, (rsub, r  ), (1,  1), 4), # right diagonal
            product_in_direction(grid, (rsub, r+3), (1, -1), 4), # left diagonal
            largest,
         )
```

It is annoying that we iterate over two different ranges. If we update our `product_in_direction` function to employ a range check, then we can avoid the need for that:

```
def product_in_direction(grid, start, direction, steps):
    x0, y0 = start
    dx, dy = direction

    if  not(0 <= y0                  < len(grid) and
            0 <= y0 + (steps - 1)*dy < len(grid) and
            0 <= x0                  < len(grid[y0]) and
            0 <= x0 + (steps - 1)*dx < len(grid[y0])):
        return 0

    product = 1
    for n in range(steps):
        product *= grid[y0 + n*dy][x0 + n*dx]
    return product
```

Now we just iterate over all indices:

```
#horizontal and vertical
for y in range(len(grid)):
    for x in range(len(grid[y])):
        largest = max(
            product_in_direction(grid, (x, y),   (1,  0), 4), # horizontal
            product_in_direction(grid, (x, y),   (0,  1), 4), # vertical
            product_in_direction(grid, (x, y  ), (1,  1), 4), # right diagonal
            product_in_direction(grid, (x, y+3), (1, -1), 4), # left diagonal
            largest,
        )
```

Note how the variable names `x` and `y` more clearly express what they actually mean than `h` or `rsub`.

To sum up what I did:

1. picked appropriate data structures
2. factored out common code, using functions if appropriate
3. abstract details like bounds checking away

Comment: I was about to write all that, but I thought it would be easier to wait for you, then upvote yours instead....

Comment: Nice answer. Have you thought about using numpy? It could offer some more efficient constructs/abstractions.

Comment: @Nobody good point: using numpy would hide most of the loops. OTOH I think that using explicit loops is easier to understand and to explain: OP seems fairly new to Python, so maybe it wouldn't be wise to introduce a library that changes how the language behaves.

Answer (score 5):

- `xrange(0, N)`  to  `xrange(N)`
- name your loop variables something meaningful, like `row` and `col`
- create some variables for the indices you need, e.g. `one_cell_up = grid[h*whatever]`
- do you need a list of largest numbers, or just one largest number?
- what is 17 and what is 20? If you created `GRID_SIZE = 20` it'd be more obvious
- Might a list (rows) of lists (cols) be a more intuitive data structure?
- Better comments would help people understand your code, which is important. It'd take me 15, 20, who knows how many minutes to walk through this algorithm (which I'm not going to do) or 30 seconds to read some comments.
- anytime you repeat the same big chunk of code, `grid[h*10...hsub+3]`, just store it in a variable
- you might check out the `step` argument to xrange, so you can get steps of 10 instead of `h * 10` everywhere
- check out [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)